# insert big images...cut in two parts, LaTeX

Tags: image, latex, figure

i would like to know how can i cut a figure in a way that some part is show in one page and the continuation in other page. Actually it just take the all figure to the next page and i get a lots of space empty that  really looks ugly.

Comment: belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: wuou nice, i didn't knew about that site

Comment: While I would advise you to use [Tex, LaTeX and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of questions, the existence of the Stack Exchange site does *not* render latex off topic here.

Comment: You are looking for the `viewport`.
See http://just-tech.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/split-big-image-to-two-in-latex.html for instance. Now I realized how old this question is, but maybe someone else needs this too.

Answer (score 0):

I would just cut the image into two outside of the LaTeX environment and insert them separately.